# How to understand the pronunciation of "nod" and "node"?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

As we know, "nod" pronounces /nɒd/ while "node" pronounces /nəʊd/ (In US style?).

So why does the extra "e" change the vocal of letter "o" entirely?

My mother language is Chinese, therefore, it seems to be little hard for me to understand the exact rules of pronunciation with respect to spelling. What resources (maybe books?) can I invoke if I'd like to precisely predict how a coined word or the one which is unfamiliar pronounce?

Comment: English spelling is notoriously unpredictable. So in the end you will have to look up a word in a dictionary to make sure you pronounce it correctly. But this difference in sound between -/ɒd/ and -/əʊd/ is very common for words ending on *-od* and *-ode*, respectively, so this will help you predict the pronunciations of words such as *lode, sod, code, pod,* etc. Similarly, there are the pairs id/ide, ad/ade, ud/ude, and ed/ede.

Comment: US style would be /nad/ and /nod/. American /o/ has [ow] (not [əw]) as the principal stressed allophone.

Comment: Join ELL and participate to learn interesting things in English like this. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=Flyp9GdUZG08GxFV_g6lKw2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "extra e" (or "silent e") at the end of a word is a *convention* which serves as a sign that the **preceding** *short* vowel should be elongated into a *long* vowel. It was introduced by [Richard Mulcaster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Mulcaster) in 1582 via his book [Elementarie](http://books.google.com/books?id=QcJ4AAAAIAAJ) wherein he called it a "qualifying e". The [Wikipedia article on the "silent e"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_e) makes for fascinating reading.

The rule is, however (and as with most aspects of English orthography), inconsistently employed. While *node*, *side*, and *rate* all involve *long* vowels, words such as *love*, *give*, and *sieve* do not.

Wikipedia has [other pages on English spelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aEnglish_spelling) that might prove useful to you.